# How to create/alter files in Delayed Job/Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, delayed-job

I need one of my delayed jobs to generate a set of files in a particular directory. Unfortunately, this directory may not exist, so I need to create it first, but the problem is that the web server doesn't have access to the parent directory to create it.

I know I could create a separate script run with admin access that generates the directory, but it seems silly to move that logic out of my job where I'm actually generating the files.

The other alternative is that I could generate the files in `/tmp` or somewhere else, and have my script move the directory/files to the proper place, but tmp doesn't seem like a very secure place.

Are there any "standard" solutions to this problem? I couldn't really find anything when searching Google.

Comment: Don't run the script with admin access. Just create a directory prior to running your script and give write access to the user running your script. I think this is more of an administration question than a delayed_job one =)

Comment: You could put in dir like tmp but that is persistant and accessible by delayed_job, and have second scripts that has more rights to take files and put them on proper place